# \setfontsize doesn't seem to set the baseline skip

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing

For a custom title page I need to set the font size to a specific value not covered by any of the standard `\Large` etc. font sizes. Therefore, I use the `\fontsize` command. Reducing to a minimal example my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\begin{document}

{\noindent\fontsize{24pt}{29pt}\selectfont
\bfseries This is a\\ long title that is split\\ over multiple lines}

\vspace{2cm}
This is normal text.
\end{document}
```

This does change the font size, however it doesn't seem to change the baseline skip resulting in ugly line spacing. See image below:

[image]

The following code seems to do the trick

```
\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\fontsize{24pt}{29pt}\selectfont
\bfseries This is a\\ long title that is split\\ over multiple lines}
```

However this seems to be a bit overcomplicated and I don't see why the first code doesn't work. What is the easiest/recommended way to set the font size in my case?

Comment: Add `\par` before the closing brace...

Comment: Line spacing is determined at the end of the paragraph, here just outside the ending }. Try adding a \par before }

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks! That does indeed do the trick. Care to add this as an answer so that I can accept it as a solution?

Comment: @daleif Thanks for explaining the reason why.

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate; the linked question is about `\LARGE`, but it's exactly the same problem.

Comment: @karlkoeller I was searching with 'fontsize' as a key word so missed that one.

Comment: @JanvanderLaan Never mind!